# powershell Exception calling "Replace" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null

Tags: powershell-3.0

While calling this function, I get the exception calling null error.

Code:

---

```
if(Test-Path($Env:TEMP))  {

    $hsPrefDataDirectories = Get-ChildItem "$Env:TEMP" | where {$_.Name -match "hsperfdata"} | Format-Table name -hideTableHeaders | Out-String -stream    
    $hsPrefDataDirectories = [regex]::Replace($hsPrefDataDirectories, "^\s+", '')
    $hsPrefDataDirectories = [regex]::Replace($hsPrefDataDirectories, "\s+", ',')
    $hsPrefDataDirectories = [regex]::Replace($hsPrefDataDirectories, ",$", '')
    $hsPrefDataDirectories = $hsPrefDataDirectories.split(",")
    .....
    $hsPrefDataDirectories = $hsPrefDataDirectories.split(",")
```

---

```
Error: 

Exception calling "Replace" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input"

...

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your code (what are you trying to do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because in your "$Env:TEMP" folder nothing matches the string "hsperfdata".

Make sure the $hsPrefDataDirectories is not null before trying to replace characters.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that and let you know.

Comment: It didnt error when I added a if condition to check if the dir is not null 
if($hsPrefDataDirectories -ne $null){

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `$hsPrefDataDirectiories` is null.
If it's something you can't control, you can use a comparison that will skip it if its value is null:

```
if($null -ne $hsPrefDataDirectiories){
    {your code...}
}
```

Make sure `$null` is on the **left side** of the comparison. For more info about this: [Should $null be on the left side of the equality comparison? (-eq with arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217913/should-null-be-on-the-left-side-of-the-equality-comparison-eq-with-arrays)