# Registry Key Exist True of False Output

Tags: powershell, registrykey

I have what I would consider a simple power shell script that I am trying to run. The script will basically check for the existence of the RegKey and return a value with an output of 0 or 1.

The issue I have is that my test results are not consistent. Ex. Reg key does not exists and the script is executed the correct value is returned, 0. I manually add the key to the registry and run the script again expected a Write-Output of 1 but 0 is what is being returned. Now if I change the parameter in the if statement from $null to something like $false then the correct output is returned until I go back and repeat my test process.  I hoping that someone may have the time to take a look at what I have written and point me in the right direction.

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR
Test-Path -Path 'HKCR:\Installer\UpgradeCodes\59DD538593C91FA40B60EB02250187C0*'
if($path -eq $null) {Write-Output 0}
else
{Write-output 1} 
 remove-psdrive -name HKCR
```

Comment: Where does your `$path` variable come from? Instead of evaluating its value, you should evaluate the result of `Test-Path`.

Comment: In any case, [`$null` should be on the lefthand side of the equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58217913/1701026)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **[`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path), like all `Test-*` cmdlets in PowerShell, returns a *Boolean* value,** i.e. either `$true` or `$false`, so you shouldn't compare it to `$null`; instead, simply use it as-is in a *conditional*.
- There is no need to create a PowerShell drive just so you can access the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive<sup>[1]</sup>; you can simply **use the `registry::` PS provider prefix to access a native registry path**.

Therefore:

```bash
if (Test-Path -Path registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\59DD538593C91FA40B60EB02250187C0*) {
  1  # same as: Write-Output 1
}
else {
  0  # same as: Write-Output 0
}
```

If, by contrast, you wanted to **get the specific key(s) that the wildcard expression matches**, use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item):

```bash
$path = Get-Item -Path registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\59DD538593C91FA40B60EB02250187C0*
if ($null -eq $path) {  # Always place $null on the LHS
  'not found'
}
else {
  'found at least one'
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is actually a *composite* view of two distinct registry subtrees: the machine-level
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and the user-level `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. That is, you see the *union* of keys from these subtrees in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`; if a registry *value* exists in *both* locations, the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` value takes precedence.</sup>