# get-process - Unable to retrieve some process information and command line

Tags: powershell

I've 2 questions regarding the code below :

**Question 1:**

For some unknown reason, the following code does not retrieve information from certain processes.
However, he manages to recover the sha256
Could you please explain why this behavior and how to fix address this behavior ?

```
Path is Null
WmiPrvSE
- [(PID=5356) () Description=]
-- Path="None (SHA256=AD938C303F12EA8D164433CC7BA46FC7B9AE00F6F899E308D4317DAB46E25642)

-----
Get-FileHash : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Path », car il a la valeur Null.
Au caractère C:\Users\LEFBE\Desktop\Klic-20-12-2021\Process.ps1:4 : 33
+ $FileHash = (Get-FileHash -Path $_.Path -Algorithm SHA256 -ErrorActio ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [Get-FileHash], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Get-FileHash
```

**Question 2:**

I'm having trouble retrieving the command line launched by the process. Could you please help me to get this information?

**The code :**

```
get-process | ForEach-Object {
$Name = $_.Name
$Desc = $_.Description
$FileHash = (Get-FileHash -Path $_.Path -Algorithm SHA256 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).hash 
$ID = $_.ID
$Path = $_.Path
$CP = $_.Company
$CL = $_.Commandline

if ($Path -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "Path is Null"
    $Path = "None"
    Write-Host "$Name" 
    Write-Host "- [(PID=$ID) ($CP) Description=$Desc]" 
    Write-Host "-- Path=""$Path (SHA256=$FileHash)"
    Write-Host $CL
    Write-Host "-----"
    }
    else 
    {
    Write-Host "$Name" 
    Write-Host "- [(PID=$ID) ($CP) Description=$Desc]" 
    Write-Host "-- Path=""$Path (SHA256=$FileHash)"
    Write-Host $CL
    Write-Host "-----"
    }
}
```

**Update 23/12/2021**

The updated code works better than the first. (manage Null $Path value)
On the other hand, no command line can be obtained yet.

```
get-process | ForEach-Object {
$Name = $_.Name
$Desc = $_.Description
$ID = $_.ID
$Path = $_.Path
$CP = $_.Company
$CL = $_.Commandline

IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Path)) {            
    $Path = "None"
    $FileHash = "None"
    write-Host "$Name" 
    Write-Host "- [(PID=$ID) ($CP) Description=$Desc]" 
    Write-Host "-- Path=""$Path (SHA256=$FileHash)"
    Write-Host $CL
    Write-Host "-----"
} else {
    $FileHash = (Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.Path  -Algorithm SHA256 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).hash         
    Write-Host "$Name" 
    Write-Host "- [(PID=$ID) ($CP) Description=$Desc]" 
    Write-Host "-- Path=""$Path (SHA256=$FileHash)"
    Write-Host $CL
    Write-Host "-----"
}
}
```

Thanks for your help,
LEFBE

Comment: [`$null` should be on the left side of the equality comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996703/1701026)

Comment: Like that : ($null -eq $Path) ? If yes, the same error as question 1 appear

Comment: Yes, also use the [`-LiteralPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/1701026) parameter

Comment: These are two known PowerShell gotchas, from a windows point of view, I question if you have always access to the `.path` property/file.

Comment: @iRon: Not sure if it's here that I need to add lateralpath it is correct ? - (Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $_.Path -Algorithm SHA256 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).hash

Comment: @LEFBE - i suspect that you are seeing a _leftover_ value. try clearing the `$FileHash` variable before you try to set it. ///// also, why don't you test for the `$_.Path` value BEFORE you try to use it?  [*grin*] ///// also also, the `$_.Path` value is hidden for a large number of processes when you grab the info _without_ admin privs. plus, there are still some that will not report the path at all.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've updated the original code with your suggestion and it work as expected. I try to find a way to address the second part of my question regarding commandline information. Thanks to you and Iron :)

Comment: @LEFBE - kool! [*grin*] glad to have helped a little bit ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated property with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) to generate your new object. As for *"having trouble retrieving the command line"*, I'm assuming you're unable to capture the output of your script with `Out-File` or similar, this is because `Write-Host` sends the output to the [Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) and it's output can't be captured unless [redirected (`6>&1`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Name, Description, @{
    Name = 'Hash'
    Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.Path -Algorithm SHA256).Hash }
}, ID, Path, Company, CommandLine
```