# How to convert many files encoded (ANSI, UTF8 BOM etc.) to UTF8 without BOM with powershell script?

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I'm trying to convert ANSI and UTF-8 BOM files to UTF-8 without BOM only. I have found a code that works to do that but in my files the word "président" from ANSI file, for exemple, is converted to "prxE9sident" or "pr?sident" (problem with accident é) in UTF8.

The script powershell code that I run in my parent folder:

```
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
$source = "path"
$destination = "some_folder"

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force) {
    if ($i.PSIsContainer) {
        continue
    }

    $path = $i.DirectoryName -replace $source, $destination
    $name = $i.Fullname -replace $source, $destination

    if ( !(Test-Path $path) ) {
        New-Item -Path $path -ItemType directory
    }

    $content = get-content $i.Fullname

    if ( $content -ne $null ) {

        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($name, $content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
    } else {
        Write-Host "No content from: $i"   
    }
}
```

Any solution to keep accents well from ANSI and other files ?

Comment: [`$Null` should be on the left hand side of the equality comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996703/1701026). If your file is closed with a newline, the last item in the `$Content` array is `$Null` which evaluates to [`$False`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans) for `if ( $content -ne $null ) { ...` and therefore doesn't even update your file.

Comment: It works thank you ! Now I observe that my problem is only with UTF8 BOM files that should be converted to UTF8 without BOM (and no ANSI file), do you think there is any easy way to do that with this code ? Thank you

Comment: I think my last comment was actually incorrect.

Comment: Try: `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($name, $content, ([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)))`

Comment: It works perfectly !! Many thanks for your answers and reactivity. Have a nice day !

Comment: If you use powershell 7, utf8nobom is the default format for set-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two [PowerShell Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644807/1701026) in the condition:

```
if ( $content -ne $null ) { ...
```

1. [`$Null` should be on the left hand side of the equality comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996703/1701026)
2. If your file is closed with a newline, the last item in the `Get-Content` results array is `$Null`

This might cause the concerned condition to unexpectedly evaluate to `$False` and therefore your script doesn't even update the required files.

Based on the additional comments, to save you files as ANSI, you should use the [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($name, $content, ([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)))
```