# Is there any Powershell script or how can i modify this script to import multiple ips as a csv file if a vm has multiple ip addresses?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, inventory

Is there any Powershell script or how can i  modify this script to  import multiple ips as a csv file if a vm has multiple ip addresses ?
This is my existing script

```
# Create Report Array
$report = @()

# Get all the VMs from the selected subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Get all the Network Interfaces
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null } 

foreach ($nic in $nics) {

$ReportDetails = "" | Select-Object  ip-address, vm_name, interface_name

$vm = $vms | Where-Object -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 

$ReportDetails.vm_name = $vm.Name 
$ReportDetails.ip-address = [String]$nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
$ReportDetails.interface_name = $nic.Name 
$report += $ReportDetails
```

}

```
$report | Sort-Object VMName | Format-Table ip-address, vm_name, interface_name
$report | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $reportFile
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general recommendation, you should try to [avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026), besides [$null` should be on the left side of the equality comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996703/1701026).

For the concerned script and expanding the `ip_address` property this would mean:

```
# Get all the VMs from the selected subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Get all the Network Interfaces
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $Null -ne $_.VirtualMachine } 

$ReportDetails = foreach ($nic in $nics) {
    $vm = $vms | Where-Object -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress.foreach{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            vm_name = $vm.Name 
            ip_address = $_
            interface_name = $nic.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help and tips. After modification i am getting this error. 

At line:16 char:15
+             ip-address = $_
+               ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:11 char:42
+ $ReportDetails = foreach ($nic in $nics) {
+                                          ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral

Comment: The script suggestion was based on your own properties where `ip-address` is either a typo or should be quoted (I have changed it in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

csv is not designed to support properties with multivalues (e.g. array). you could use json instead:

```
$report | convertto-json | set-content -path $reportFile
```

Or if it has to be a csv you can flattern the structure or join the array to a delimited string, e.g.

```
$ReportDetails.ip-address = ($nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -join "|")
```

Comment: Okay thats great. But how can i  fetch all the ip addresses of a vm incase a vm has multiple ip addresses.