Pester script is not working in Azure Pipeline (YAML)
I am facing a typical issue regarding Powershell Pester. The pester script is not working in one 'task', but working in other task. In-fact none of the Az module functions are working.
Note:[ The service connection is successfully connected azure subscription]
Error:
VERBOSE: Command [Set-AzContext] succeeded.
LastWriteTime : 4/13/2024 9:04:31 PM
Length        : 0
WARNING: You're using Az.Storage version 6.1.1. The latest version of Az.Storage is 6.1.3. Upgrade your Az modules
using the following commands:
Update-Module Az.* -WhatIf    -- Simulate updating your Az modules.
Update-Module Az.*            -- Update your Az modules.
##[error]    [-] has the available storage account name 2.57s (2.55s|12ms)
##[error]     ParameterBindingException: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
##[error]     at , D:\a\1\s\deploymenttest\predeployment.Tests.ps1:28
Tests completed in 13s
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Yaml Code::
stages:
- stage: Partner
  displayName: Dev
  jobs:
  - deployment: Dev_deployment
    displayName: Dev deployment
    pool:
        vmimage: windows-latest
    environment: Dev
    strategy:
        runOnce:
            deploy:
                steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: AzurePowerShell@5
                  displayName: Pre Deployment Validation Status
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: SC-Partner
                    ScriptType: InlineScript
                    Inline: |
                        Set-Location $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
                        New-Item $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\PreTestResults.xml -ItemType File

                        $container = New-PesterContainer -Path ./deploymenttest/predeployment.Tests.ps1 -Data @{ environment='dev'}
                        $pesterConfig = [PesterConfiguration]@{
                          Run = @{
                              Exit = $true
                              Container = $container
                          }
                          Output = @{
                              Verbosity = 'Detailed'
                          }
                          TestResult = @{
                              Enabled      = $true
                              OutputFormat = "NUnitXml"
                              OutputPath   = "PreTestResults.xml"
                          }
                          Should = @{
                              ErrorAction = 'Continue'
                          }
                        }

                        Invoke-Pester -Configuration $pesterConfig
                        #Invoke-Pester -Container $container

                    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
                    failOnStandardError: true
                - task: PublishTestResults@2
                  displayName: 'Publish Pre Deployemnt Validation Results'
                  inputs:
                    testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
                    testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\PreTestResults.xml'
                    mergeTestResults: true
                    testRunTitle: 'Predeploy Tests'                                    
                - task: AzurePowerShell@5
                  displayName: Lab Dev Deployment
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: SC-Partner
                    ScriptType: InlineScript
                    Inline: |
                        Set-Location $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
                        #Get-ChildItem -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Filter *.psd1 -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
                        ./deployment/master.ps1 -environment "dev" -commonparamfilename "common"

                    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
                    failOnStandardError: true

Pester Scripts::
param(
        [string]$environment
    )

BeforeAll {
    $rgConfig = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path .\parameters\resourcegroup.psd1
    $rgname = $rgConfig.$environment.rgname 
    $commonConfig = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path .\parameters\common.psd1
    $location = $commonConfig.common.location
    $stgConfig = Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path .\parameters\storageaccount.psd1
}

Describe 'DevopsLab' {
    Context 'Parameter Validation' {

        it 'has the resourse group <rgname> staring with rg_'{

            $rgname.substring(0,3) | Should -Be 'rg_'
        }

        it 'has the available storage account name'{
            $stgNameAvailability
            $stgId=(Get-AzStorageAccount -EA SilentlyContinue -ResourceGroupName $rgconfig.$environment.rgname -Name $stgConfig.$environment.stgName).Id
            if($stgId -eq $null){
                $stgNameAvailability = Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability -EA SilentlyContinue -Name $stgConfig.$environment.stgName
            }
                
            $stgNameAvailability | Should -Be -BeNullOrEmpty
        }        
    }
}


I'm gong to guess it's Should -Be -BeNullOrEmpty - you probably need either -Be or -BeNullOrEmpty but not both. As an aside, in if($stgId -eq $null), it's a good idea to get used to putting $null on the left side - i.e. if($null -eq $stgId) because unexpected things can happen when comparing with an array if $null is on the right - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996703/3156906

Will your PowerShell script/command  container = New-PesterContainer -Path ./deploymenttest/predeployment.Tests.ps1 -Data @{ environment='dev'}  work if you run it in local PowerShell prompt or it only fails when running in pipeline agent environment? It may help isolate the cause by the script or environment. And by the way, what do you mean by working in other task? Have you compared the script and environment to run the two tasks?
